# Why am I getting EACCESS writing to a chmod 777 directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

I moved my `/tmp` to another hard disk to save wear on the SSD.

```
ls -aolh /
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   10 Jan  3 17:22 tmp -> /store/tmp

ls -aolh /store
drwxrwxrwx 13 root   4.0K Jan  7 13:51 tmp

ls -aolh /store/tmp/
drwxrwxrwx 13 root   4.0K Jan  7 13:54 .
```

I can create files in `/tmp/` as a non-root user, but KMail won't start, the mysql error log contains

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibVLn1jR' (Errcode: 13)
150107 13:49:56  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
150107 13:49:56 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150107 13:49:56 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150107 13:49:56 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: innodb
150107 13:49:56 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Errcode 13 is EACCESS. The file `/tmp/ibVLn1jR` does not already exist. How can this be a permissions failure?

Comment: Is `/store/tmp` a network or other unusual mount? Please include the output of `mount | grep /store`.

Comment: `/dev/sdb2 on /store type ext4 (rw)`

Answer (score 2):

Is SELinux enabled?  (The `getenforce` command will return `Enforcing` if it is.)

If so, SELinux policy is likely preventing mysqld from writing to a tmp directory that is symlinked to another directory -- a directory for which no policy is defined. You can test this by running `setenforce 0` as root to put the system into permissive mode.  If Kmail works, then you'll need to configure policy for the /store directory.

If you're running a GUI desktop, the `sealert` utility will indicate the problem and tell you what to do.  Otherwise, you'll need to use one of the SELinux command line audit tools.

Comment: `command not found: getenforce`

Comment: In case /usr/sbin is not in PATH, you may want to try /usr/sbin/getenforce.  If that doesn't work, then the libselinux-utils package is probably not installed and SELinux is disabled.

Comment: Doesn't look like libselinnux-utils is either installed or available. I'm using Kubuntu 14.10. libselinux1 is installed.

Comment: Oops.  [Ubuntu and its derivatives use AppArmor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481293/selinux-implementation-in-ubuntu) instead of SELinux.  Sorry, I live in the Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS world and have zero knowledge about AppArmor. Suggest tagging as an Ubuntu question to raise visibility there.